# Disk space suddenly used up for no apparent reason in 20.04

Tags: boot, hard-drive, 20.04

I went to bed last night with about 180gb of unused space on my SSD and when I woke up got an error that my root drive was out of space. After I restarted I couldn't boot back into Ubuntu until I booted in recovery mode to delete unused packages and clear a bit of space. Here's my `df -h`:

[image]

And here's the disk use analyzer:

[image]

The only thing I had running when I left it was a web scraper, but it was a very small job and the whole file ended up being 87mb. Any ideas on why this happened and how to fix it?

EDIT: syslog and kern.log each seem to be taking up ~78gb when I look at each file in my var folder. Not sure why that happened though or how much of this stuff in the var folder I can just trash. I'd really like to know why they got to this size before I just delete them and forget about it.

EDIT2: Not sure if it's relevant, but the `gnome-shell` process is eating up about 15-40% of CPU while simply moving my mouse which I don't remember it doing in the past.

EDIT3: I peeked in the syslog and found this over and over:

```
May  3 00:00:31 me-ThinkPad-T480s kernel: [ 3260.559176] audit: type=1400 audit(1588478431.146:58519): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=4545 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May  3 00:00:31 me-ThinkPad-T480s kernel: [ 3260.559236] audit: type=1400 audit(1588478431.146:58520): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.discord.discord" name="/proc/1398/cmdline" pid=4545 comm="Discord" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
May  3 00:00:31 me-ThinkPad-T480s kernel: [ 3260.559243] audit: type=1400 audit(1588478431.146:58521): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=4545 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May  3 00:00:31 me-ThinkPad-T480s kernel: [ 3260.559384] audit: type=1400 audit(1588478431.146:58522): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=4545 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May  3 00:00:31 me-ThinkPad-T480s kernel: [ 3260.559395] audit: type=1400 audit(1588478431.146:58523): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.discord.discord" name="/proc/1420/cmdline" pid=4545 comm="Discord" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
May  3 00:00:31 me-ThinkPad-T480s kernel: [ 3260.559430] audit: type=1400 audit(1588478431.146:58524): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=4545 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
```

I also saw a lot of other things so I have no idea how relevant this is in particular, it's hard to tell what's meaningful in these logs (and also hard to read a lot of what's happening).

Comment: It's safe to delete a runaway logfile, but your system is shouting as loud as it can that something is wrong - read elements of the new logfile (as it respawns and burgeons) to learn exactly what is wrong.

Comment: [Here is a discussion of the issue in detail](https://github.com/snapcrafters/discord/issues/23)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The snap application called Discord is the bad guy...

From the `Ubuntu Software` center...

---

*All-in-one voice and text chat for gamers that's free, secure, and works on both your desktop and phone.*

*Snaps are confined, as such Discord may be unable to perform some of the tasks it typically does when unconfined. **This may result in the system log getting spammed with apparmor errors**. Granting access to the system-observe interface when in the snap will enable the features, and thus reduce the logging.*

```
snap connect discord:system-observe
```

---

**Note**: granting access may be a security risk, and a privacy issue.

**Note**: from @mchid, see https://github.com/snapcrafters/discord/issues/23

Personally, because of the privacy and security concerns, I wouldn't use Discord. I'd remove it from my system. Any snap app that needs access outside of its sandboxed environment to perform its actions are very suspect... especially ones that have code to figure out what other apps you're running at the same time as Discord.

Then delete the large syslog and kern.log files.

Comment: Thanks. I imagine you would have said so if possible but I have to ask if there is any way to prevent this without opening myself up to such a risk?

Comment: @snapcrack  See the discussion pointed to by mchid.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you wouldn't use Discord? If you personally have no use for it, sure it makes sense to remove it from your system, but that reasoning does nothing for people who do have a legitimate use for the program. So saying that you, personally, would not use the program, without adding your reasoning (whether because you don't need it or you think it's actively harmful or something else), seems to add little value to this answer.

Comment: @DavidZ I've updated my answer. Discord has some very real privacy and security concerns. Any snap app that needs access outside of its sandboxed environment to perform its actions are very suspect... especially ones that have code to figure out what other apps you're running at the same time as Discord.

Comment: Thanks, the new version is somewhat better.

Comment: @DavidZ Updated slightly more. Read the previously included link for more detail...

Comment: @heynnema Discord has a feature where they detect when you are running games and shows it to your "friends". https://github.com/snapcrafters/discord/issues/43#issuecomment-524582590

Comment: @RayWu I wouldn't want any program that scans my system every 5 seconds to determine what I'm running, telling others, and/or generating **tons** of syslog errors.

Comment: @heynnema You can turn the feature off. The client download is not obfuscated. This snap is created by the community and not Discord Inc. so they have no obligation to fix anything, and the issue stems from a problem with the snap sandbox where the `stat` syscall on /proc/XXX succeeds due to the permissions being write but the `open` call fails. Ideally they would both fail if the sandbox prevented a file from being accessed.

Comment: @RayWu And what else are they scanning/stating, and where is that data going? Some overseas server? Not my system.

Comment: @heynnema As I said, the client-side Electron parts of the application are unobfuscated and unminified and Electron security features are turned on to prevent the minified browser code from accessing your system.