# syslog filling with this error message, discord?

Tags: kernel, syslog

I noticed that my /var/log/syslog file is constantly being filled by this errors each second if I do have Discord app open. It continues until I quit Discord. Then stops. All I can understand from these messages is that they are related to Discord app.

```
root@muyustan-ubuntu:/var/log# tail syslog
May 28 03:46:24 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126189.613514] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626784.957:124600): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:24 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126189.613537] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626784.957:124601): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:24 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126189.613642] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626784.957:124602): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:24 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126189.613705] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626784.957:124603): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:24 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126189.613755] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626784.957:124604): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:24 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126189.613810] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626784.957:124605): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:24 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126189.613868] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626784.957:124606): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:24 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126189.613935] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626784.957:124607): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:24 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126189.614024] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626784.957:124608): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:24 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126189.614092] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626784.957:124609): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
root@muyustan-ubuntu:/var/log# tail syslog
May 28 03:46:29 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126194.618007] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626789.961:124719): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:29 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126194.618058] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626789.965:124720): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:29 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126194.618125] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626789.965:124721): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:29 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126194.618188] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626789.965:124722): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:29 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126194.618669] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626789.965:124723): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:29 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126194.618783] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626789.965:124724): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:29 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126194.618998] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626789.965:124725): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="/usr/bin/evince"
May 28 03:46:29 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126194.619059] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626789.965:124726): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:29 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126194.619190] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626789.965:124727): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:29 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126194.619807] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626789.965:124728): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
root@muyustan-ubuntu:/var/log# tail syslog
May 28 03:46:29 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126194.618669] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626789.965:124723): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:29 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126194.618783] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626789.965:124724): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:29 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126194.618998] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626789.965:124725): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="/usr/bin/evince"
May 28 03:46:29 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126194.619059] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626789.965:124726): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:29 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126194.619190] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626789.965:124727): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:29 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126194.619807] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626789.965:124728): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:34 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126199.622860] kauditd_printk_skb: 85 callbacks suppressed
May 28 03:46:34 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126199.622864] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626794.968:124814): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:34 muyustan-ubuntu kernel: [126199.622918] audit: type=1400 audit(1590626794.968:124815): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="snap.discord.discord" pid=125686 comm="Discord" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
May 28 03:46:39 muyustan-ubuntu systemd[1985]: gnome-launched-discord_discord.desktop-125532.scope: Succeeded.
```

Notice the last line, after I quit discord, it is no longer pushing errors. So, any idea what this is and how to solve?

Thanks.

Comment: See my accepted answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234854/disk-space-suddenly-used-up-for-no-apparent-reason-in-20-04/1234881#1234881

Comment: thanks, i think i'll delete it and go with online version.

Comment: If you'd like, please vote for my answer at the above link. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema sorry, should've done earlier, my bad.

Answer (score 4):

My syslog error messages in 18.04 from discord were slightly different, but I suspect that the cause may be the same.:

```
apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.discord.discord" name="/proc/2613/cmdline" pid=4255 comm="Discord" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=
```

My error seemed to be caused by discord trying to detect what games I am currently playing so that it can automatically update my discord status message. You can turn this function off by:

1. Open Discord
2. Click on **User Settings**. In my version, this is a cogwheel at the bottom left of the discord screen with my profile picture.

[image: Discord User Settings]

3. Click on **Game Activity** under **APP SETTINGS** on the left.
4. Turn off **Display currently running game as a status message**
   [image]

Credit: [piark](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/discord-ptrace-apparmor-denials/5099/15)

---

If the turning off the **Display currently running game as a status message** does not work. Then you have three options:

1. Give discord the permission it seeks and take the privacy/security risks:

   - Open a terminal
   - type `snap connect discord:system-observe`
   - Further info, see [snapcraft-discord](https://snapcraft.io/discord)
2. Modify discord AppArmor profile to suppress the error messages and take the compatibility/functionality risks:

   - Open a terminal
   - `gedit admin:///var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.discord.discord`
   - Deny the source of the error by adding either or both of these two lines at the bottom of the file before the `}`

     - `deny /proc/@{pid}/cmdline r,`
     - `deny ptrace (read),`
   - Save and close gedit
   - Load the new AppArmor profile by typing `sudo apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.discord.discord`
   - [credit xNinjaKittyx](https://github.com/snapcrafters/discord/issues/23#issuecomment-591765410)
3. Install the apt version of discord

   - remove snap discord - `sudo snap remove discord`
   - Download and install the [latest discord deb package](https://discord.com/api/download?platform=linux&format=deb)

Comment: No such option in the Discord version I had under Ubuntu 20LTS: Stable 106868 (4527af0) Host 0.0.16 Linux 64-Bit (5.4.0-90-Generic)

Comment: Is the version installed from the _deb_ package granted the `system-observe` privileges?

Comment: @Petr yes, I guess so.