# Overheating Ubuntu 20.04 Dell Inspiron 7570

Tags: overheating

Since I updated to Ubuntu 20.04, I have overheating problems with my laptop and it is slow.

My processor is an Intel® Core ™ i7-8550U, Nvidia Geforce 940MX, I have Dual boot Windows10 / Ubuntu. I

do not have much knowledge in Linux; but, looking I could use the sensors command, I have attached the output below:

**sensors command**
[image: sensors command]

**top command**
[image: top command]

**free -h command**
[image: free -h command]

**sysctl vm.swappiness command**
[image: sysctl vm.swappiness command]

**sudo dmidecode -s bios-version command**
[image: sudo dmidecode -s bios-version command]

**nvidia driver**
[image: nvidia driver]

**kernel version**
[image: kernel version]

**ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions command**
[image: ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions]

**ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions command**
[image: ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions]

**tail /var/log/syslog command**
[image: tail /var/log/syslog]

**snap list command**
[image: snap list]

**dpkg -l *discord* | grep ii command**
[image: dpkg -l *discord* | grep ii]

**ls -alh /var/log/syslog and ls -alh /var/log/kern.log**
[image]

Comment: Is it caused by the low fan rev or some process is keeping pressure on your CPU? Have you overclocked your CPU ( from UEFI menu for example)?

Comment: Edit your question and show me a screenshot of `top`, and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. What version Nvidia driver? Can you switch to Intel video instead of Nvidia?

Comment: @Parsa Mousavi The computer is new and the fans are working properly, I have recently noticed that when I run the discord application it starts to slow down and heat up, this did not happen in Ubuntu 18.04, however I have not tested how it responds when running other applications besides the browser and some editors of text

Comment: @heynnema I already executed the commands and put the results, I recently updated the BIOS version and on the Nvidia driver I am not using the proprietary driver.

Comment: What kernel version are your running? Edit you answer to include the output of `uname -sr`

Comment: @ldias Thanks for replying, I just put the kernel version with the command you said

Comment: **Totally excellent response Fernando! Thanks!** I do see a number of concerns. gnome-shell and Discord. Please add the following to your question... `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `tail /var/log/syslog`. Also, is Discord a snap application? Use `snap list` to find out.

Comment: @heynnema Thank you very much, I have added the commands and also checked if discord is an instant application, and apparently if it is an instant application

Comment: I've started a partial answer. Please do the gnome-shell part asap and report back. For Discord, please show me the output of the `dpkg` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**gnome-shell**

When viewed with the `top` command, gnome-shell should only be using 3% or less of CPU. Yours is using 85%. This is usually because of a bad gnome-shell extension.

Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and **immediately** disable **ALL** extensions. Then reload gnome-shell this way:

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, in the box that appears, type <kbd>r</kbd>, then hit the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key

Now view the `top` command again, and confirm that gnome-shell is only using about 3% of CPU. Monitor the `sensors` command and confirm that temps are below 50C.

We'll discuss re-enabling gnome-shell extensions later.

`cpupower` is a very suspect extension.

Once the `top` and `sensors` commands are in line, we'll enable **ONE EXTENSION AT A TIME**, and continue to monitor these commands. Understand that the impact from re-enabling an extension may not be seen right away.

**Discord**

re: *When I run Discord, the gnome-shell increases to 85%, 95% of CPU.*

In its snap application format, Discord is a major security and privacy problem. Use `snap list` to determine if your Discord is a snap application. Use `dpkg -l *discord* | grep ii` to determine if Discord is a standard binary application.

From one of my previous answers regarding Discord...

[Disk space suddenly used up for no apparent reason in 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234854/disk-space-suddenly-used-up-for-no-apparent-reason-in-20-04/1234881#1234881)

The snap application called Discord is the bad guy...

From the `Ubuntu Software` center...

---

*All-in-one voice and text chat for gamers that's free, secure, and works on both your desktop and phone.*

*Snaps are confined, as such Discord may be unable to perform some of the tasks it typically does when unconfined. **This may result in the system log getting spammed with apparmor errors**. Granting access to the system-observe interface when in the snap will enable the features, and thus reduce the logging.*

```
snap connect discord:system-observe
```

---

**Note**: granting access may be a security risk, and a privacy issue.

**Note**: from @mchid, see https://github.com/snapcrafters/discord/issues/23

Personally, because of the privacy and security concerns, I wouldn't use Discord. I'd remove it from my system. `sudo snap remove --purge discord`. Any snap app that needs access outside of its sandboxed environment to perform its actions are very suspect... **especially ones that have code to figure out what other apps you're running at the same time as Discord.**

Then delete the large /var/log/syslog and /var/log/kern.log files.

If you wish to continue to use Discord, uninstall the snap version as per my instructions above, and install the binary version, which can be downloaded at https://discord.com/download. Continue to monitor `top` and `sensors`.

Comment: I followed the steps and now the gnome is between 1% and 3% when I run Discord, the gnome increases to 85%, 95%, I have verified it, and indeed discord is an instant app, should I try a standard binary app?

Comment: @FernandoAlvarez When you say instant app, do you mean a snap app, or something else? Use the `snap` and `dpkg` commands  that I gave you to figure this out. Report back.

Comment: Thanks i added the commands

Comment: @FernandoAlvarez Yup, it's a snap app. Show me `ls -alh /var/log/syslog` and `ls -alh /var/log/kern.log`.

Comment: While the application is open everything works normal, when I enter a voice channel the problem begins

Comment: @FernandoAlvarez I updated the Discord text in my answer, and included instructions for uninstalling the snap version, and installing the binary version.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help. I found it very useful and now I have a little more knowledge when this happens again.

Comment: @FernandoAlvarez You're very welcome! It was a genuine pleasure helping you.