# gnome corruption

Tags: boot, gnome, 20.04, freeze

after update from 19.10 to 20.04  gnome has problem in display . it's slow . VisualStudio Code and jetbrains ide or discord suddenly freeze 
and this is my desktop on startup [Desktop Picture](https://gofile.io/d/05NOTr)

I have tried nvidia-driver440 and 435 now its 435.

```
s -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions:
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 12 sorush sorush 4096 مئی     27 23:49 .
drwx------  4 sorush sorush 4096 مئی     29 11:29 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 sorush sorush 4096 مئی      3 21:29 alternate-tab@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  4 sorush sorush 4096 مئی      9 15:48 clipboard-indicator@tudmotu.com
drwxr-xr-x  8 sorush sorush 4096 مئی      9 15:48 cpupower@mko-sl.de
drwxr-xr-x  5 sorush sorush 4096 مئی      9 15:48 dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com
drwxr-xr-x  5 sorush sorush 4096 آوریل   29 23:31 EasyScreenCast@iacopodeenosee.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 sorush sorush 4096 مئی     27 23:49 gTile@vibou
drwxr-xr-x  4 sorush sorush 4096 آوریل   12 22:32 openweather-extension@jenslody.de
drwxr-xr-x  4 sorush sorush 4096 آوریل   15 18:24 touchpad-indicator@orangeshirt
drwxr-xr-x  2 sorush sorush 4096 مئی      5 21:16 tray-icons@zhangkaizhao.com
drwxr-xr-x  4 sorush sorush 4096 مئی      9 15:48 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com

ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions:

total 60
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4096 مئی     28 17:24 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 مئی     28 15:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 مئی     28 17:24 apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 مئی     28 17:24 auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 مئی     28 17:24 drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 مئی     28 17:24 horizontal-workspaces@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 مئی     28 17:24 launch-new-instance@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 مئی     28 17:24 native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 مئی     28 17:24 places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 مئی     28 17:24 screenshot-window-sizer@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 مئی     28 15:24 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 مئی     28 17:24 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 مئی     28 17:24 window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 مئی     28 17:24 windowsNavigator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 مئی     28 17:24 workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

```
sudo grep -i stack /var/log/syslog*:
/var/log/syslog:May 30 00:43:20 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2718]: == Stack trace for context 0x5607448c96e0 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 30 00:43:20 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2718]: == Stack trace for context 0x5607448c96e0 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 30 08:29:52 sorush-FX503VD kernel: [    0.066684] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:on, heap free:off
/var/log/syslog:May 30 08:29:52 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
/var/log/syslog:May 30 08:29:52 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
/var/log/syslog:May 30 08:29:52 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
/var/log/syslog:May 30 08:31:26 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2588]: == Stack trace for context 0x55b01ec606e0 ==
/var/log/syslog:May 30 08:31:26 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2588]: == Stack trace for context 0x55b01ec606e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 21:37:56 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2672]: == Stack trace for context 0x55dce55c26e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 27 21:37:56 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2672]: == Stack trace for context 0x55dce55c26e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 10:14:42 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 10:14:42 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 10:14:42 sorush-FX503VD kernel: [    0.066309] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:on, heap free:off
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 10:14:43 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 10:20:01 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2780]: == Stack trace for context 0x562df58236e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 10:20:01 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2780]: == Stack trace for context 0x562df58236e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 10:26:27 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 10:26:27 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 10:26:27 sorush-FX503VD kernel: [    0.066833] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:on, heap free:off
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 10:26:28 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 10:27:50 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2164]: == Stack trace for context 0x55f67f8556e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 10:27:50 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2164]: == Stack trace for context 0x55f67f8556e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 13:05:32 sorush-FX503VD kernel: [    0.067054] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:on, heap free:off
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 13:05:32 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 13:05:32 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 13:05:32 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 13:57:10 sorush-FX503VD kernel: [    0.066178] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:on, heap free:off
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 13:57:10 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 13:57:10 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 13:57:10 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 13:58:42 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2594]: == Stack trace for context 0x55e9260a16e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 13:58:42 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2594]: == Stack trace for context 0x55e9260a16e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 14:55:48 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[9267]: == Stack trace for context 0x560dcdc636e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 14:55:48 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[9267]: == Stack trace for context 0x560dcdc636e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 15:23:26 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 15:23:26 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 15:23:26 sorush-FX503VD kernel: [    0.067039] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:on, heap free:off
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 15:23:26 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 15:24:48 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2180]: == Stack trace for context 0x561680f246e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 15:24:48 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2180]: == Stack trace for context 0x561680f246e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 15:26:20 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 15:26:20 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 15:26:20 sorush-FX503VD kernel: [    0.066950] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:on, heap free:off
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 15:26:20 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 15:27:48 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2573]: == Stack trace for context 0x5555793f76e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 15:27:48 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2573]: == Stack trace for context 0x5555793f76e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 17:25:52 sorush-FX503VD kernel: [    0.067164] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:on, heap free:off
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 17:25:52 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 17:25:52 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 17:25:53 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 02:37:24 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 02:37:24 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 02:37:24 sorush-FX503VD kernel: [    0.066596] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:on, heap free:off
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 02:37:24 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 22:09:48 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2646]: == Stack trace for context 0x564efc6996e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 28 22:09:48 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2646]: == Stack trace for context 0x564efc6996e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:26:26 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:26:26 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:26:26 sorush-FX503VD kernel: [    0.066820] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:on, heap free:off
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:26:26 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: message repeated 3 times: [ == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: message repeated 3 times: [ == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: message repeated 3 times: [ == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: message repeated 3 times: [ == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: message repeated 3 times: [ == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: message repeated 3 times: [ == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: message repeated 3 times: [ == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: message repeated 3 times: [ == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: message repeated 3 times: [ == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: message repeated 4 times: [ == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: message repeated 6 times: [ == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: message repeated 3 times: [ == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: message repeated 4 times: [ == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: message repeated 3 times: [ == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:54:10 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2519]: message repeated 4 times: [ == Stack trace for context 0x5599af4246e0 ==]
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:55:27 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[8060]: == Stack trace for context 0x56311a0dd6e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 00:55:27 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[8060]: == Stack trace for context 0x56311a0dd6e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 01:10:43 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 01:10:43 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 01:10:43 sorush-FX503VD kernel: [    0.067291] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:on, heap free:off
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 01:10:43 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 01:21:56 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 01:21:56 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 01:21:56 sorush-FX503VD kernel: [    0.066417] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:on, heap free:off
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 01:21:56 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 11:14:04 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 11:14:04 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 11:14:04 sorush-FX503VD kernel: [    0.067060] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:on, heap free:off
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 11:14:04 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 11:19:21 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2795]: == Stack trace for context 0x55d84a8f66e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 11:19:21 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2795]: == Stack trace for context 0x55d84a8f66e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 17:18:29 sorush-FX503VD kernel: [    0.066907] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:on, heap free:off
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 17:18:29 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 17:18:29 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 17:18:29 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 17:22:32 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2722]: == Stack trace for context 0x55ba8679a6e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 20:36:50 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2722]: == Stack trace for context 0x55ba8679a6e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 20:36:50 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2722]: == Stack trace for context 0x55ba8679a6e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 20:36:50 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2722]: == Stack trace for context 0x55ba8679a6e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 20:36:50 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2722]: == Stack trace for context 0x55ba8679a6e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 20:36:50 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2722]: == Stack trace for context 0x55ba8679a6e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 20:36:50 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2722]: == Stack trace for context 0x55ba8679a6e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 20:36:50 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2722]: == Stack trace for context 0x55ba8679a6e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 20:36:50 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2722]: == Stack trace for context 0x55ba8679a6e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 20:36:50 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2722]: == Stack trace for context 0x55ba8679a6e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 29 20:36:50 sorush-FX503VD gnome-shell[2722]: == Stack trace for context 0x55ba8679a6e0 ==
/var/log/syslog.1:May 30 05:11:30 sorush-FX503VD kernel: [    0.067141] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:on, heap free:off
/var/log/syslog.1:May 30 05:11:30 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
/var/log/syslog.1:May 30 05:11:30 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
/var/log/syslog.1:May 30 05:11:30 sorush-FX503VD systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
```

```
top:
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                     
   2588 sorush    20   0 5893796 250384 117328 R  11.6   1.5   1:47.47 gnome-shell                                                                                                                                 
   2357 sorush    20   0  696496  60244  46092 S   5.3   0.4   1:31.40 Xorg                                                                                                                                        
   2776 sorush    20   0  507424  77272  46968 S   3.0   0.5   0:03.40 guake                                                                                                                                       
   8771 sorush    20   0 2651564 375864  97092 S   1.3   2.3   0:57.53 Telegram                                                                                                                                    
   4501 sorush    20   0 1410604 146920  84792 S   1.0   0.9   0:41.03 persepolis                                                                                                                                  
   8254 sorush    20   0 4711968 172036  96428 S   0.7   1.1   0:11.33 chrome                                                                                                                                      
  10136 sorush    20   0   15220   4536   3776 R   0.7   0.0   0:00.13 top                                                                                                                                         
    288 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:01.80 kworker/u16:3-i915                                                                                                                          
   1126 root      20   0   81884   3644   3308 S   0.3   0.0   0:00.15 irqbalance                                                                                                                                  
   1216 root      20   0 1482208  42616  23292 S   0.3   0.3   0:03.37 containerd                                                                                                                                  
   1927 shadows+  20   0  113612  12544   6928 S   0.3   0.1   0:09.45 v2ray-plugin_li                                                                                                                             
   2493 sorush    20   0  314196   7860   5988 S   0.3   0.0   0:03.35 ibus-daemon                                                                                                                                 
   2548 sorush    20   0  162892   8040   7220 S   0.3   0.0   0:01.21 at-spi2-registr                                                                                                                             
   2686 sorush    20   0  596412  57944  46644 S   0.3   0.4   0:01.36 dolphin                                                                                                                                     
   2861 sorush    29   9 2412228 203124  87228 S   0.3   1.2   0:10.32 kited                                                                                                                                       
   3491 sorush    20   0 1289760 232228  50900 S   0.3   1.4   0:08.84 gnome-software                                                                                                                              
   3510 sorush    20   0 1065492 307252 157116 S   0.3   1.9   2:56.67 chrome                                                                                                                                      
   4142 sorush    20   0  357756  91512  65384 S   0.3   0.6   0:17.48 chrome                                                                                                                                      
   4381 sorush    20   0 4727508 112012  74944 S   0.3   0.7   0:34.74 chrome                                                                                                                                      
   4628 sorush    20   0   74740  29196  12024 S   0.3   0.2   0:52.95 aria2c                                                                                                                                      
   4706 sorush    20   0 8927932 168892  93088 S   0.3   1.0   0:13.16 chrome                                                                                                                                      
   8339 sorush    20   0 4729004 182176  89640 S   0.3   1.1   0:12.50 chrome                                                                                                                                      
   8512 sorush    20   0 4766336 217444 100980 S   0.3   1.3   0:34.92 chrome                                                                                                                                      
   9137 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:03.37 kworker/6:2-events
```

```
snap list
Name               Version                     Rev   Tracking         Publisher       Notes
core               16-2.44.3                   9066  latest/stable    canonical✓      core
core18             20200427                    1754  latest/stable    canonical✓      base
gnome-3-28-1804    3.28.0-16-g27c9498.27c9498  116   latest/stable    canonical✓      -
gnome-3-34-1804    0+git.3009fc7               33    latest/stable    canonical✓      -
gtk-common-themes  0.1-36-gc75f853             1506  latest/stable/…  canonical✓      -
keepassxc          2.5.4                       784   latest/stable    keepassxreboot  -
mailspring         1.7.8                       488   latest/stable    foundry376✓     -
p3x-onenote        2020.4.185                  72    latest/stable    patrikx3        -
spotify            1.1.26.501.gbe11e53b-15     41    latest/stable    spotify✓        -
vlc                3.0.10                      1620  latest/stable    videolan✓       -
```

Comment: Do you have Nvidia? If so, what version driver? Discord has real security and privacy issues. Check `tail /var/log/syslog` and I'll bet that you've got a ton of repeating errors, from Discord. Also, edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: Regarding Discord... please see my accepted answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234854/disk-space-suddenly-used-up-for-no-apparent-reason-in-20-04/1234881#1234881. Please remember to vote for it if it's helpful.

Comment: yes i have GTX1050

Comment: Thanks for the info. Please tell me what version Nvidia driver you have. Also please show me the `top` command, as I need to check CPU usage for gnome-shell and Discord. Also show me `snap list`. You have too many gnome-shell extensions, and some of them are installed into an improper place. All of this relates to the slowness.

Comment: Please also show me `sudo grep -i stack /var/log/syslog*`.

Comment: i have added what you said please check it @heynnema

Comment: You may have more than one problem, but there's enough for me to start to put together an answer for you. Give me a few minutes. Also, please show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Thanks.

Comment: Also, let's redo one previous command, with modifications... `sudo grep -i stack /var/log/syslog* -A5`. If this output if large, paste it in at paste.ubuntu.com.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: it did not solve my problem . so deleted ubuntu and migrated to arch (manjaro).
every thing is ok here and I have all extensions because I did not purge my home directory and I'm using the old one . 
thank for your attempt

Comment: By installing Manjaro, /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions got wiped of all rogue extensions, which is exactly part of my answer. **If you would have followed my answer exactly, you'd probably still be running Ubuntu, without all of the problems**.

Answer (score 0):

You may have more than one problem.

**gnome-shell**

We'll start with gnome-shell extensions. You have too many of them, some of them are **crashing** gnome-shell, some of them are causing high CPU% usage for gnome-shell, one of them may be causing the screen artifacts, some of them are installed twice, and some are installed in an improper place.

Start by going to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and **DISABLING ALL EXTENSIONS**. Then restart gnome-shell with:

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, in the box type <kbd>r</kbd>, then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

I suspect that the screen artifacts have disappeared, and things should be running faster. If that's true, we'll go to the next step.

Remove these extensions...

```
sudo rm -r /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/*gcampax.github.com
```

Reinstall these missing extensions...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
```

Restart gnome-shell again with:

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, in the box type <kbd>r</kbd>, then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Once the system is stable, re-enable **ONE EXTENSION AT A TIME**, whilst keeping an eye out for screen artifacts, "Stack trace" errors in `/var/log/syslog*`, or high gnome-shell usage as viewed in the `top` command. gnome-shell CPU% usage should be less than 3%.

Do NOT reinstall extension "packs" from gcampax.github.com.

**Discord**

Discord has some security and privacy issues. Please see my accepted answer at [Disk space suddenly used up for no apparent reason in 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234854/disk-space-suddenly-used-up-for-no-apparent-reason-in-20-04/1234881#1234881) for details.

My biggest concern is that it "spies" on what other applications that you're running along with Discord. That's none of "their" business.

**Update #1:**

Deleted Ubuntu and migrated to arch (Manjaro).